# "0: command not found" error while running a bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

This is my script:

```bsh
echo "please enter any number"
read n
a= $(($n % 2))
if [ $a -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "EVEN"
else
    echo "ODD"
fi
```

This is the script's output:

```
$ source first.sh 
please enter any number
2
0: command not found
ODD
```

It's like what ever value I give only the else part is gets executed.

What could be the reason of the error here?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with ubuntu. It is a shell scripting problem. unix.stackexchange.com is a better place for this question. Please take hints from http://www.d0wn.com/bashcheck-if-a-number-is-even-or-odd/

Comment: [https://www.shellcheck.net/](https://www.shellcheck.net/) helps a lot while scripting.

Comment: @turbulence Shell scripting questions are welcome in AskUbuntu. Please see this [meta discussion](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic) about that topic.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the space after `a=`. The variable assignment should be `a=$(($n % 2))`.

In general, spaces are important in Bash scripting. As stated in [cas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413578/322816) in this relevant [Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413576/what-are-some-cases-that-the-number-of-spaces-do-matter-in-bash-or-other-shell) (which I think is worth checking out):

> - Things not separated by whitespace are considered to be one "word".
> - Things separated by one-or-more whitespace characters are considered to be two (or more) words.

This has the interesting implication that if the variable assignment is written as `a=$(($n % 2))`, the value right next to `=`, i.e. `$(($n % 2))`, gets assigned to `a`, as expected.

However, if the variable assignment is written as `a= $(($n % 2))` the value right next to the `=` is just an empty space, which will be assigned to `a`. Bash will treat `a` as an [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) with the value of an empty string and then proceed to evaluate `$(($n % 2))`, which, depending on the value of `n`, will be either `0` or `1`. That's why you'll get the error `0: command not found` or `1: command not found`, depending on the case.

After that, the script will continue to the `if-else` statement. The expression `[ $a -eq 0 ]` always returns the following error (not shown in your question), due to the value of `a` being an empty string:

```
[: -eq: unary operator expected
```

So, finally, the `else` part will always get executed, thus your script will always return `ODD`.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has its own helpful options to determine what's happening.  the -v echos each line as read, and the -x prints out the line executed (after variable substitution, etc.)

```
$ bash -vx first.sh
bash -vx first.sh
echo "please enter any number"
+ echo 'please enter any number'
please enter any number
read n
+ read n
4
a= $(($n % 2))   
+ a=           <======As a comment mentioned, a space causes problems
+ 0
first.sh: line 3: 0: command not found
if [ $a -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "EVEN"
else
    echo "ODD"
fi
+ '[' -eq 0 ']'
first.sh: line 4: [: -eq: unary operator expected
+ echo ODD
ODD
```